# Not able to set leader lines using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, excel, scatter-plot, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create scatter chart using `xlsxwriter`. Further, I want to show some specific data labels (hence I am using `custom` data labels) along with its leader lines. 
I know, from the documentation, that to see leader lines, we must move it manually. However, even when I am setting `leader_lines` option to `True`, I am still seeing `Show Leader Lines` option in output excel file is unchecked and even if I move data labels manually leader lines are not visible. 
[image] 
 
Any idea how to handle this problem? 
I am using `'3.0.3'` version of `xlsxwriter` and `Python 3.10.5`.

I am having below code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import xlsxwriter.utility as utl

a = [[222.724, 23.2381],
     [219.798, 27.2969],]

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('trial.xlsx')
sheetName = 'sheet1'
ws = wb.add_worksheet(sheetName)

ws.write_column(1,0, ['A1', 'A2'])
ws.write_row(1,1,a[0])
ws.write_row(2,1,a[1])

custom_labels = []
for i in range(2):
    cell = utl.xl_rowcol_to_cell(1+i, 0)
    custom_labels.append({'value':f'={sheetName}!{cell}'})

chart = wb.add_chart({'type':'scatter'})
chart.add_series({'name':'Goodman','categories':[sheetName,1, 1, 2, 1],
    'values':[sheetName,1, 2, 2, 2],
    'marker':{'type':'circle','fill':{'color': 'yellow'},'border': {'color': 'blue'},},
    'line':{'none':True},
    'data_labels': {'value': True, 'custom':custom_labels, 'leader_lines': True,
                    'border': {'color': 'red'},
                    'fill':   {'color': 'yellow'}},})

ws.insert_chart(3,4, chart)

wb.close()
```

Comment: Rightly or wrongly I think that the setting `leader_lines` doesn't work with Scatter charts. If you were to simply change the chart type from `scatter` to `pie` in your code, the option would be enabled, a Pie Chart being the expected chart to use with this param. Anyway @jmcnamara will no doubt comment at some point whether this is in error or by design.

Comment: The issue here is that  leader lines were only supported for Pie charts in the original xlsx version of Excel (2007) and the associated file format. XlsxWriter writes the leader line XML element for all chart types but Excel ignores it for anything other than Pie charts. It doesn't even show up in the Excel 2007 interface for other chart types. However, in some later version of Excel (>= 2012) it was added to the interface and a new XML element was added to the file format. That addition isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. I'll make a feature request but, for now, I think the documentation should be clarified from saying "mainly used in pie charts" to "currently only supported for pie charts".